# GETPIVOTDATA formula not functioning with nested substitute formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

Why is it not possible to substitute the following part of the GETPIVOTDATA item5 data:

[...];"[Time].[Month]";**"[Time].[Month].&[1]"**)

The nested formula for the highlighted part is:

=CONCAT(CHAR(34);"[Time].[Month].&[";MONTH(C1&1);"]";CHAR(34))

Which should return **"[Time].[Month].&[1]"**

But when i nest it inside the item part of getpivotdata, it just gives me a ref error.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't include CHAR(34).

Comment: remove the two char(34) ssections